# How to get total count of incoming and outgoing MMS in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the total number of outgoing and incoming MMS in Android. I have tried searching for information on how to do this but haven't been able to find a solution that works. Can anybody provide information on how I would achieve this?

Comment: What code (even unworking) do you have so far? Showing us what you already have will allow us to help you more easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri mmsUri = Uri.parse("content://mms");

//msg_box is the equivalent of type in SMSs, 1=Inbox and 2=sent
Cursor mmsCursor = getContentResolver().query(mmsUri,new String[] {"_id","msg_box"}, "msg_box=1 OR msg_box=2", null, null);
int mmsCount = mmsCursor.getCount();
```

or

```
Uri mmsInboxUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/inbox");
Uri mmsSentUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/sent");

Cursor mmsInboxCursor = getContentResolver().query(mmsInboxUri ,new String[] {"_id"},  null, null);
Cursor mmsSentCursor = getContentResolver().query(mmsSentUri ,new String[] {"_id"}, null, null);
int mmsCount = mmsInboxCursor.getCount() + mmsSentCursor.getCount();
```

The second one should work, I'm not too sure about the 1st one and I can't really test it atm, but if the first one works, use that, it should be more efficient.